# How can we retrieve Link list from a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linked-list

I have SQL Server table structure like below

```
Id   title   nextID
-------------------
1      w      2
2      x      3
3      y      4
4      z     null
```

How can I get the result in the form of LinkedList by using entity framework?

Like This

```
Id:1
tile:w
nextId:2
nextNode => Id:2
            tile:x
            nextId:3
            nextNode => Id:3
                        tile:y
                        nextId:4
                        nextNode => Id:4
                                    tile:z
                                    nextId:null
                                    nextNode:null
```

Comment: Why do you need a linked list?  The DataTable can be used instead.

Comment: I want to ask questions to the end-user in a series manner that's why I need a linked list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would need to get the relevant rows out *first*, and *then* form the linked list yourself. Assuming that the data is more complex in reality (i.e. there exist other rows that aren't in the same chain), this makes it harder to query - you'd either need to perform multiple round-trips (as you iteratively discover the next link in the chain), or you'd need to write your own recursive CTE (or a `while` loop in SQL, if you prefer) to fetch the entire chain in one go. In either scenario, EF isn't really going to go out of its way to help you do this - you're going to have to do that yourself. And by the time you're doing *that*, I wonder whether it might make more sense (or at least: sense) to switch to `hierarchyid` as the implementation; as I understand it: this should allow you to query everything in the same hierarchy in a single query (noting that in your case, each level in the hierarchy would only have at most a single child)